# How to avoid the multiple use of 'isnan' to filter inconsitent datasets?

Tags: arrays, matlab, datetime, numbers, complex-numbers

I have two corresponded (has a relation and has the same dimension) dataset:

1. `Time`
2. `Salinity`

Some data in salinity dataset is NaN.

I can remove the NaN value by:

```
 Salinity_new=Salinity(~isnan(Salinity))
```

But it will not correspond to the `Time` dataset any more.

How can I remove the corresponded time in also?

Thanks

Comment: `Time_new=Time(~isnan(Salinity))`?

Comment: `nanElements = isnan(Salinity);`? If you do not have enough memory for this, you should consider another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments of Diavakar and patrik are correct. To sum it up and get this question answered, some further remarks.

```
mask = isfinite(Salinity) 
[Time,Salinity] = deal( Time(mask), Salinity(mask) )
```

`isfinite` is the same as `~isnan` - but with one computation step less, its about 50-90% faster. By introducing a `mask` you're avoiding the double use of `isfinite`. `deal` just saves you some space.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is the following:

```
indexes = find(isnan(Salinity)==1);
Salinity(indexes) = []; 
Time(indexes) = []
```

In this way you eliminate the non-numerical value from your vectors.