# How to avoid the multiple use of 'unique' to filter inconsitent datasets?

Tags: matlab, unique, duplication

I have two corresponded (has a relation and has the same dimension) dataset:

1. `Time`
2. `Salinity`

Some data in Time dataset are duplicated.

I can remove the duplicate value by:

```
Time_new=unique(Time,'rows');
```

But it will not correspond to the Salinity dataset any more.

How can I adjust the corresponded Salinity Data in also?

Thanks

(Adopted from [How to avoid the multiple use of 'isnan' to filter inconsitent datasets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631737/how-to-avoid-the-multiple-use-of-isnan-to-filter-inconsitent-datasets))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the additional output arguments of [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/unique.html):

```
[Time_new,idx_un,~] = unique(Time,'rows');
Salinity_new = Salinity(idx_un, :);
```

Comment: Thanks Bentoy13 , your answer give me idea to use indexing method. Good Day